# Table data display in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following table: how to adjust the height and width automatically for the table.

i.e, if the data is more it should display all the data else present data in a fashionable manner

```
<table id="mytable"> 
  <tr>
    <td>more data.............................................................................</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the nothing should be wrapped wither in case of large chunks of data or small chunks of data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'nowrap' in the tag or in a style:

```
<td nowrap>...</td>
```

--- or ---

```
<style>
  .cell {
    white-space:nowrap;
  }
</style>

<td class="cell">...</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css `overflow` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use percentage widths and heights for your `<td>` tags and they will be adjusted relative to each other regardless of the content that's inside them.